# How to replace a character in value of input with another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to figure out a way to replace part of a string in an input value, but haven't been able to get it working.

the input field looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{'value': 'e', 'provider': {'provider_id': '6', 'dmnid': '2446-0'}}" name="Link" />
```

and i want to replace single qoute with double qoute.
how can I change my value of input .
i've been writing the below code but it does not work and does not recognize the single code .

here is my snippet :

```js
$('input[name=Link]').val(function(index, value) {
   return value.replace(''', '"');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="{'value': 'eydpZCc6IwNDA5J30=', 'provider': {'provider_id': '6', 'dmnid': '2446-0'}}" name="Link" />
```

Comment: str.replace(/'/g, '"');

Comment: Using `/\'/g` will replace all the single quote to double quote :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change to:  value='{"value": "e",...}'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/\'/g` to replace all the single quote to double quotes at global level. Using `\'` and `\"` will be safe to use when you use quotes in your expressions.

```js
$('input[name=Link]').val(function(index, value) {
   return value.replace(/\'/g, '\"');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="{'value': 'eydpZCc6IwNDA5J30=', 'provider': {'provider_id': '6', 'dmnid': '2446-0'}}" name="Link" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple Regex `/'/g` for that.

*PS: The `g` makes your regex global.*

```js
$('input[name=Link]').val(function(index, value) {
   return value.replace(/'/g, '"');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="{'value': 'eydpZCc6IwNDA5J30=', 'provider': {'provider_id': '6', 'dmnid': '2446-0'}}" name="Link" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems with current code is that:

1. You're not escaping the single quote in the string.
2. Even if you escape it, it will just replace the first occurrence of the single quote in the target string.

You can use RegEx with `g` flag to replace all the occurrences of single quote in the string:

```js
$('input[name=Link]').val(function(index, value) {
   return value.replace(/'/g, '"');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="{'value': 'eydpZCc6IwNDA5J30=', 'provider': {'provider_id': '6', 'dmnid': '2446-0'}}" name="Link" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i'd do it with JQuery:

```
<input type="text" value="{'value': 'e', 'provider': {'provider_id': '6', 'dmnid': '2446-0'}}" name="Link" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var link=$('input[name=Link]');
link.val(link.val().split("'").join('"'));
</script>
```